# using a wild card in a script in a directory name

Tags: windows, shell, scripting, wildcard

I'm writing a script in which i want to copy a file from my directory to the "Start Menu\Programs\Startup" in the computer. 
My problem is - this script is for several computers and from some reason in each one the administrator has a different name,so the path "C:\Documents and Settings**administrator**\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" is not suitable for all.

I'm looking for a way to use a wild card in the directory name . something like:
 "C:\Documents and Settings\administrator*\Start Menu\Programs\Startup", so my script will  work in all computers. (the name is unknown from advance but i do know that it will start with the word 'administrator')

Any ideas?
Thanks,

Tamar

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more clever ways, but one way would be to use the `for` command.  Something like the following:

```
cd "c:\documents and settings"
for /D %%f in (administrator*) do copy yourfile "%%f\start menu\programs\startup"
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the variable

```
%userprofile%
```

could be useful for you. It gives you directly the path "C:\Documents and Settings\CurrentLoggedUser".

Comment: I'm trying to write : fileCopy("c:\MyDir\MyFile", %userprofile%\start menu\Programs\Startup) and it's not working. what is wrong?

Comment: try echo %userprofile% to see what you get. May be you need to use quotes : "%userprofile%\start menu\Programs\Startup"

Comment: @Tamar: %userprofile% won't necessarily be available this way inside a scripting environment other than cmd.exe. It's an environment variable and needst to be accessed as such. For example in vbscript: `userprofile=createobject( "WScript.Shell" ).expandenvironmentstrings("%userprofile%")`